# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'android\app\src\main\assets\index.android.bundle'

Tags: react-native, signed-apk, metro-bundler

I created react-native init project

then I run the project using react-native run-android it will run without any issues.

When i try to build apk using below comment

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

I m facing this error

error ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'android\app\src\main\assets\index.android.bundle'. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'android\app\src\main\asset\index.android.bundle'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve this by first navigating to :   `'android\app\src\main` folder in your app and there create a folder named `assets` ,  so hence while bundling react native will create the `index.android.bundle` in `android\app\src\main\assets` folder.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the folder assets exists in your project's  'android\app\src\main' ; if it does, it implies that the file 'index.android.bundle' does not; simply create the file on the folder. If the folder is not there, both the folder and the file must be created.